# React-Select with Formik - S6544 promises should not be misused

Tags: typescript, formik, react-select

I have following code

```
<Select 
   options={publisherOptions} 
   onChange={selectedOption => formik.setFieldValue("publisherId", selectedOption?.value)} />
```

and it works! However I am getting typescript warning **S6544**

> Promises should not be misused.
> Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.

[image]

Is there some better way how to code this to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Don't return the promise from the function.

```
selectedOption => {
    formik.setFieldValue...;
}
```

Adding braces around the function body means it returns whatever the `return` statement says instead of the result of the single expression. (Since there is no `return` statement, it returns `undefined` (a void value as is expected by the context).

Comment: I added the braces but it is still underlined
`<Select options={publisherOptions} onChange={selectedOption => { formik.setFieldValue("publisherId", selectedOption?.value) }} />`

Comment: `formik.setFieldValue` is expected to be awaited but I don't know how.